# How many calls can Workbox Analytics save to disk?

Tags: google-analytics, workbox

I am looking into using [Workbox Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics) for reporting usage statistics from an Android app with users who are mainly offline (with sporadic connections to internet). [Segment Analytics](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/mobile/android/) has an event limit of 1000; it saves up to 1000 calls on disk. What is the event limit of Workbox Analytics? I could not find this in the Workbox documentation but might have overlooked something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no hard limit. Each request that needs to be replayed is serialized and stored in IndexedDB, and there is an [overall storage quota](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/#:%7E:text=Chrome%20allows%20the%20browser%20to,browser%20to%20use%20more%20storage.) that applies to all types of storage for a given web origin. But since the Google Analytics ping requests are rather small, I would not expect them to contribute significantly to storage usage (vs., say, images or other subresources).

The main way that `workbox-google-analytics` limits the queue of requests to replay is with an expiration timer, [which is set to 2 days](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/83887869103400ccbc4bfe8b0d16529108f7a413/packages/workbox-google-analytics/src/utils/constants.ts#L12).